# domain class field not being displayed on view page

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I am unable to view all of the below fields when I run my grails app the " Cost" field is not being displayed on the view page, the fields are displayed on the add page. If I remove the "name" field the "cost" field is then displayed. Is there a field limit that im not aware of ?

```
package racetrack

class Race {

    String name
    Date startDate
    String city 
    String state 
    BigDecimal distance 
    BigDecimal cost 
    Integer maxRunners = 100000

    static constraints = {

        name()
        startDate()
        city()
        state()
        distance()
        cost()
        maxRunners()
    }

}
```

List.gsp -

```
<%@ page import="racetrack.Race" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="layout" content="main" />
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'race.label', default: 'Race')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav">
            <span class="menuButton"><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message code="default.home.label"/></a></span>
            <span class="menuButton"><g:link class="create" action="create"><g:message code="default.new.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></span>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <h1><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
            <g:if test="${flash.message}">
            <div class="message">${flash.message}</div>
            </g:if>
            <div class="list">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>

                            <g:sortableColumn property="id" title="${message(code: 'race.id.label', default: 'Id')}" />

                            <g:sortableColumn property="name" title="${message(code: 'race.name.label', default: 'Name')}" />

                            <g:sortableColumn property="startDate" title="${message(code: 'race.startDate.label', default: 'Start Date')}" />

                            <g:sortableColumn property="city" title="${message(code: 'race.city.label', default: 'City')}" />

                            <g:sortableColumn property="state" title="${message(code: 'race.state.label', default: 'State')}" />

                            <g:sortableColumn property="distance" title="${message(code: 'race.distance.label', default: 'Distance')}" />

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <g:each in="${raceInstanceList}" status="i" var="raceInstance">
                        <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">

                            <td><g:link action="show" id="${raceInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: raceInstance, field: "id")}</g:link></td>

                            <td>${fieldValue(bean: raceInstance, field: "name")}</td>

                            <td><g:formatDate date="${raceInstance.startDate}" /></td>

                            <td>${fieldValue(bean: raceInstance, field: "city")}</td>

                            <td>${fieldValue(bean: raceInstance, field: "state")}</td>

                            <td>${fieldValue(bean: raceInstance, field: "distance")}</td>

                        </tr>
                    </g:each>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="paginateButtons">
                <g:paginate total="${raceInstanceTotal}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: By `view` page, do you mean the `show` view or the `list` view?

Comment: I dont know what the difference is between the two ?

Comment: When using scaffolded or generated views, `list` is at URL `/controllerName/list`, show is at `/controllerName/show/1` (1 = id). There's no scaffolded `/controllerName/view`.

Comment: I'm talking about a "list" view then. URL is  - http://localhost:8080/RaceTrack/race/list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to the scaffolded `list` view, the scaffolding only renders six fields.

The basic logic (from `src/templates/scaffolding/list.gsp`) is:

```
props.eachWithIndex { p, i ->
    if(i == 0 {
        // render the field as a link to the show view
    } else if(i < 6) {
        // render the field value
    }
}
```

Note that the list of properties includes the `id`. Since you define six fields in your constraints, the last one's not being displayed (only the id + first five are).

**Edit**

To "fix" this, you have some options:

- Update the scaffolded list view code:

  1. First, run `grails install-templates`
  2. Open up `src/templates/scaffolding/list.gsp`
  3. Find the code segment above and change the condition

     Note that this will change the rendering for *all* scaffolded and generated list views.
- Generate the view and update it manually.

  It looks like you've already generated the view, so you'll just need to update it. Note that if you generate it again, it will overwrite your changes.

Comment: I've added race.groovy domain class and the generated .gsp but the generated file does'nt seme to match the domain class attributes, am I missing something ?

Comment: Even if you generate the file, it will still follow the scaffolding rule I've outlined in my answer (at the time the GSP gets generated). You'll have to change the scaffolding template or manually update the generated view to contain the fields that you want it to.

Comment: ok, the src your referring to is the grails src right ? If so why is the framework limiting the fields in this way ?

Comment: Rendering all of the fields in column form will, with enough columns, cause the UI to look bad (lots of wrapping, not enough horizontal space). Why they decided on six specifically, I don't know.